# Formating ps -u output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My objective is to get use `ps -u <user>` command and display only the `pid` and the process name in `gtk`, `textView` within `gtk.scrolledwindow`.

I am trying with the below code, but it is giving me this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please help me and tell me how I can get this?

```
    user = os.getenv('USER')
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-u', user], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)        
    while True:
        line = output.stdout.readline().split()
        str1 = str(line[0])
        str2 = str(line[3])
        string = str1 + '\t' + str2
        self.textbuffer.insert_at_cursor(string)
        if not line: 
            break
    scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)
```

Comment: When reporting errors, it is helpful to post the exact line that is causing the error.

Comment: You have a list, you are trying to access one of its items, the index you are giving it (probably 3) is not in range. The error is not that hard to decipher

Comment: str1 = str(line[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Also, post an example of the lines you've read from the `ps` command. If you just `print(line)`, or add a breakpoint and view it in pdb, it should be very obvious why `line[3]` is an `IndexError`.

Comment: Also, what did you expect `str(line[0])` to do? `line[0]` is already a string. (Or, if this is Python 3 and it's a `bytes`, you're going to get something like `'b"123"'` instead of `"123"`, which isn't very useful.)

Comment: Exactly I want to get PID and CMD. \

Comment: Is that last comment supposed to be an answer to any of the questions people have asked you?

Comment: abarnert has the correct answer for you.

Comment: @abarnert in Python 3 i am getting the same out as you illustrated. by doing str(line[0]) i want to get PID in string format.

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena: The PID is already in string format. What other format do you think you're going to get out of calling `split` on a string? And if you _are_ in Python 3, why did you tag the question Python 2.7?

Comment: @abarnert, no i am not using python3, i am using python2.7, i mention 3 just to confirm i am getting same output as you illustrated. I am also aware that if split will return me string only, but due to some reason i was not able to concatenate with '\t' so i used str func. All i need is to get only PID and CMD with tab in between.

Comment: I don't believe that adding that `str` fixed any problem. And "for some reason" is the worst possible reason to write any code. If you don't know _why_ you're doing something, you shouldn't do it. That's how you end up not understanding your own code and not able to fix anything.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your logic: You have a `while True:`, that you break out of with `if not line:`. So, you're expecting to get a blank line at the end.

But you do `line[0]` (and `line[3]`) *before* checking for that blank line. So, at the end, you will try to try to read the 1st and 4th columns of a blank line, and there are no such columns, therefore it's an `IndexError`.

The simplest fix is to just move the check up:

```
while True:
    line = output.stdout.readline().split()
    if not line: 
        break
    str1 = str(line[0])
    str2 = str(line[3])
    string = str1 + '\t' + str2
    self.textbuffer.insert_at_cursor(string)
```

A better fix is to use a `for` loop instead of trying to reproduce what it does manually with `while`, `readline`, and `break`:

```
for line in output.stdout:
    bits = line.split()
    str1 = bits[0]
    str2 = bits[3]
    string = str1 + '\t' + str2
    self.textbuffer.insert_at_cursor(string)
```